# How to get static / relocatable framework name from class name in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-frameworks, objective-c-framework

I have a string with the name of a class and I'm trying to get the framework name where the class belongs.

Things that I have tried:

1. bundleForClass

```
Class *myClass = NSClassFromString(@"ClassName");
[NSBundle bundleForClass:myClass];
```

But I can't seem to make it work with relocatable / static mach-o type.

2. Adding new method on NSObject using categories

```
// This is on NSObject+ModuleID.h
@interface NSObject (ModuleID)
- (NSString *) moduleIdentifier;
@end

// This is on NSObject+ModuleID.m
@implementation NSObject (ModuleID)
- (NSString *) moduleIdentifier { return @"Framework Name"; }
@end
```

```
Class *myClass = NSClassFromString(@"ClassName");
[myClass moduleIdentifier];
```

This doesn't work since the project include more than 1 framework.

3. Adding a new string property containing the framework name to each class in the frameworks

```
-(NSString *)moduleIdentifier
{ return @"Framework Name"; }
```

This is not feasible considering the number of the classes easily exceeds a hundred.

Is there any way to do this? Any input would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So conceptually you want something that `lldb` https://stackoverflow.com/a/40120375/5329717 yields here?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
-(NSString *)moduleIdentifier
{
    return [NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class].bundleIdentifier;
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as bundleForClass always returns the mainBundle instead of the framework when using relocatable / static mach-o type